# iPhone and Vertex Buffer Objects

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es

I've just started playing around with opengl es on the iphone the past couple of weeks and i'm looking at refactoring some of my code to use Vertex Buffer Objects(VBO). Before I do though I would like to make sure it'll be worth it. The problem is that afaik the only reason you create VBO's is to shift a chunk of data onto the graphics card so that it doesn't need to be retrieved from system ram when it's used. The iPhone however does not have any dedicated ram that I'm aware of so i'm struggling to see why I would benefit at all from using VBO's. I have seen talk around the internet with conflicting opinions and apple certainly want dev's to use it so there's probably still a reason to use them but just wanted to see if anyone on SO had an opinion to add.

Answer (score 1):

I saw no performance improvement on an iPhone 3G.  I moved a bunch of stuff to VBOs, but eventually backed it out as it made it more difficult for me to pursue other performance gains.  It's not the quick 25% performance increase that I was hoping for.

I've read somewhere that it can make a difference on the newer hardware (3GS), but I don't have references to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. (sorry).

Rob didn't see an improvement for his setup, but [here is an interesting post](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/08/05/lessons-molecules-opengl-es) that did see a large improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to existence of VBO's is the presence of static data on 3D models. The first bottleneck you encounter is the slowness of copying data to video memory (by using the unavailable glBegin/glEnd block or glVertexPointer, glBufferData and friends).

Let's imagine the old "flying toaster" screensaver. All toasts are static (changing only the position) - why waste resources copying them every frame from CPU's memory to GPU's? Copy it once with buffers and draw it with a single command. And, depending on how you do animations, even the animated toasters can be described in a static fashion.

My first 2D game I started without VBOs. When I changed to VBOs, no difference (like Rob). But, when I refactored to use more static buffers, FPS gone from 20 to 40. Since my goal was to reach 30, I was satisfied. I had some ideas to refactor even more, leaving everything static, but I don't have time now (game is on review, next one to come).